# What is the difference between "Therefore, I was wondering" and "I was, therefore, wondering"?

Tags: grammar

What is the difference between "Therefore, I was wondering....." and "I was, therefore, wondering....."?

Comment: I just read some ielts textbooks. And it mentions that "I was, therefore, wondering...." can get higher band score. So I am confused about the difference between these two sentences.

Answer (score 0):

Any difference in placing the word *therefore* in your examples is too slight to define with precision.

The second version, **however**, breaks up a sentence with a pause in a nice way that most other sentences will not have.

> Pause -- 
>   The comma ... inserts a pause into the sentence. This can be deliberately used in unusual places in order to build suspense. - [Changing Minds.org](http://changingminds.org/techniques/language/punctuation/comma.htm)

If you are writing an essay for the test, this variety, **therefore**, gives your reader (the test scoring judges) a slightly different taste in your writing, called sentence variety. That puts them in a good mood and may result in a better score for your essay. It cannot hurt unless you overuse it, which then detracts from its gentle novelty.

[How to get a 7 on your IELTS essay – **Use sentence variety.**](http://yourieltstutor.com/how-to-get-a-7-on-your-ielts-essay-use-sentence-variety/?utm_source=rss&utm_medium=rss&utm_campaign=how-to-get-a-7-on-your-ielts-essay-use-sentence-variety)